# convert NSstring date to UTC date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

i need to convert some date that i have in `NSString` to `NSString` in this format: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz`
i write this code:

**date input: date ---> 27/03/2012**

```
-(NSString *)setDateStringFormat:(NSString *)date 
 {
     NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
     [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
     //[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
     NSDate *dateFormatted = [formatter dateFromString:date];

     [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];
     [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
 return [formatter stringFromDate:dateFormatted];
 }
```

**output: 2012-03-27 00:00:00 GMT**

as you all can see i got the date in `GMT` and not in `UTC` 
some one have an idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this method..

```
-(NSString *)getUTCFormateDate:(NSString *)localDate
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

    NSDate *dateFormatted = [dateFormatter dateFromString:localDate];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFormatted];
    [dateFormatter release];
    return dateString;
}
```

Comment: i try your method but i need the string in UTC format and the output is: 2012-03-26 22:00:00

Comment: and if i add yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz it's also dont UTC

Comment: you mean if you enter 26-03-2012 the you want output is 2012-03-26 00:00:00 ??

Comment: @Sosily click this link and see my blog with Date information http://parasjoshi3.blogspot.in/2012/01/date-formate-info-for-iphone-sdk.html

Answer (score 1):

i think, Here GMT show Standard time and GMT and UTC both are same.
please look on below links:
http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/
http://www.worldtimeserver.com/convert_time_in_UTC.aspx

thanks