# utc and local date time conversion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

the server gives the UTC formatted date and time.

```
2012-11-28T10:32:15+01:00
```

the utc will be formatted to: `2012-11-28 10:32:15`
the current actual local date & time is `2012-11-28 11:32:15`

i want to save the utc format in the database and later before showing in the UI convert it to user's local date and time. i have written the following code. but the time offset is wrong. it adds 2hrs instead of 1hrs to the utc time, eventhough the time offset is + 1hrs.

```
NSDateFormatter *utc = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[utc setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[utc setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *dtUTC = [utc dateFromString:@"2012-11-28 10:32:15"];

double i =[[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] secondsFromGMTForDate:[NSDate date ]];

NSDateFormatter *dfLocal = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dfLocal setDateFormat:@"yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
[dfLocal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:i]];
NSDate *localDateTime= [dtUTC dateByAddingTimeInterval:i];
NSString *time =[dfLocal stringFromDate:localDateTime];
NSLog(@"original UTC %@  now local: %@", dtUTC, time);
```

and the logs:

```
time offset : 1.000000
original UTC 2012-11-28 10:32:15 +0000  now local: 12-11-28 12:32:15
```

it should be `2012-11-28 11:32:15` but gives  `2012-11-28 12:32:15`
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: may get some idea from this my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583253/convert-nsstring-date-to-utc-date/13583368#13583368

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok now after posting the question. i've found the solution. its magical!

```
NSDateFormatter *utc = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[utc setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[utc setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *dtUTC = [utc dateFromString:@"2012-11-28 10:32:15"];

NSDateFormatter *dfLocal = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dfLocal setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
[dfLocal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

NSString *time =[dfLocal stringFromDate:dtUTC];
NSLog(@"original UTC %@  now local: %@", dtUTC, time);
```

and the logs:

```
time offset : 1.000000
original UTC 2012-11-28 10:32:15 +0000  now local: **2012-11-28 11:32:15**
```

thanks guys for trying to help

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
[dfLocal setDateFormat:@"yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

and replace it with

```
 [dfLocal setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

Happy Coding.!!!!!

Comment: that doesnt work since it has nothing to do with adding time offset. and i tried it before :-)

Answer (score 0):

try also this code..

```
NSTimeZone* currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSTimeZone* utcTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];

NSDate *dtUTC = [utc dateFromString:@"2012-11-28 10:32:15"];

NSInteger currentGMTOffset = [currentTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
NSInteger gmtOffset = [utcTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
NSTimeInterval gmtInterval = gmtOffset - currentGMTOffset;

NSDateFormatter *dfLocal = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dfLocal setDateFormat:@"yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate* localDateTime = [[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:gmtInterval sinceDate:dtUTC] autorelease];
NSString *time =[dfLocal stringFromDate:localDateTime];
NSLog(@"original UTC %@  now local: %@", dtUTC, time);
```

i hope this help you...