# converting string to NSDate using NSDateFormatter returns in 1 year difference

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a string date in UTC format:

> "2012-11-20T05:23:02.34"

now I want the UTC NSDate object for this... and I implemented this function.

```
+ (NSDate *)utcDateFromString:(NSString *)string withFormat:(NSString *)format {
    NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    inputFormatter.timeZone =[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
    [inputFormatter setDateFormat:format];
    NSDate *date = [inputFormatter dateFromString:string];
    [inputFormatter release];
    return date;
}
```

and called it like this...

```
NSDate* submittedDate =[NSDate utcDateFromString:submittedDateString withFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS"];
```

but this returns the NSDate description as this..

> 2011-11-20 05:23:02 +0000

Now if you notice there is one year difference in the dates... can anyone explain why is this happening..?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's your 'T' in "2012-11-20T05:23:02.34"?

Comment: I just ran that code and it produced the correct answer for me. But I pasted your code into a test class and made `utcDateFromString` a method in that object, rather than a Class method on NSDate.

Comment: And I just re-tried it with your code exactly, implementing a category on NSDate. And that worked too. Sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in the dateformmater, use `yyyy` instead of `YYYY`

It should be

```
NSDate* submittedDate =[NSDate utcDateFromString:submittedDateString withFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS"];
```

That will solve the problem.

In the following link, search for YYYY.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

> It uses yyyy to specify the year component. A common mistake is to use YYYY. yyyy specifies the calendar year whereas YYYY specifies the year (of “Week of Year”), used in the ISO year-week calendar. In most cases, yyyy and YYYY yield the same number, however they may be different. Typically you should use the calendar year.

Answer (score 1):

try this bellow method..

```
-(NSDate *)getUTCFormateDate:(NSString *)localDate withFormat:(NSString *)format 
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:format];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:localDate];
    return date;        
}
```

And Use Like bellow..

```
    NSDate *dateHere = [[NSDate alloc]init];
    dateHere = [self getUTCFormateDate:@"2012-11-20T05:23:02.34" withFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS"];
    NSLog(@"Date here %@",dateHere);
```

and i get output is **Date here 2012-11-20 05:23:02 +0000**

see my another answer which return string date with UTF format..

[convert NSstring date to UTC date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583253/convert-nsstring-date-to-utc-date/13583368#13583368)[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583253/convert-nsstring-date-to-utc-date/13583368#13583368)

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava try this method and code it working perfect see output dude.. :)